# Determine what file has changed or been created

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, centos6, rhel

I'm able to connect our CentOS 6.7 server to an external LDAP successfully but the last step in the process requires something in the GUI:

System > Administration > Authentication, then checking "Authentication Method"

[image: LDAP Authentication]

I'd love to either know the exact file that this change in the GUI modifies or creates, *or* learn a method that I can use to show me which files have been created or modified in the last five minutes, for example. Of course, I have no idea which directory or directories this file was created or modified in.

I'm primarily a Mac user so we have tools in OS X that can be used for such a purpose, but I'm hoping there's an equivalent method in CentOD/RHEL.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the exact answer I was looking for but does solve my immediate problem. The following find command shows recently created files, sorted by most recent:

```
find /etc -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

Looks like the file changed by the GUI above is:

```
/etc/sysconfig/authconfig
```